# How can I solve an equation like 'x^3/3x == 4' using Scipy?

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

or another Open Source Python Library: Numpy, Matplotlib ...

Comment: Have you to solve it numerically or analytically?

Comment: [SymPy](http://live.sympy.org/): `solve(x**3/(3*x)-4, x)`

Comment: I wish I could give pre-emptive `reopen` votes...

Answer (score 2):

Use scipy's `fsolve`. Documentation found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).

Define your function in python as (must be set equal to zero):

```
def func(x):
     return x**3/(3*x) - 4
```

and solve by giving python an initial guess:

```
from optimize import fsolve  
x0 = fsolve(func, 3.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simple algebra will do:

```
x^3/3x = x^2/3 = 4
```

Simplify this:

```
x^2 = 12
```

Or:

```
x = 2*sqrt(3)
```

You don't *really* need SciPy, do you?